# Firebase Admin SDK - Verify ID exists

Tags: python, firebase

As part of our current API calls we receive the user's firebase installation ID. e.g. `ezOi0OrW6UQAuyf9m0MeRq`

Is it possible to verify the ID actually exists via the Firebase Admin SDK in Python?

Tried some of the functions regarding users in the SDK docs and kept getting user ID not found. I may be trying it in the wrong place.

Comment: Do you mean a user's Firebase Authentication UID? Can you also share the code that you've tried so we can see what's incorrect?

Comment: It is the installationID. per our app devs. I was wondering if there was anyway to confirm it was legitimate via the Firebase Admin SDK.

Answer (score 0):

decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
uid = decoded_token['uid']

Reference link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#python